# CDN image refencing

Tags: php, image

I have a website that allows users to upload their own images...
the images will get uploaded to my server at... www.mydomain.com/images/

I curently refernce an image as:

But if i wanted to use a CDN,

1. Would the images still get uploaded to my server before being copied to the CDN?
2. How would i reference the image so that it is displays the CDN image?.. bearing in mind i assume a CDN has multiple servers and multiple subdomains... so how to know which subdomain/server to reference to.

Comment: Which CDN are you using?

Comment: Most CDNs have good documentation on how to get started using it.